# Comment traduire/transposer « outrage [nom] » (par ex. « discourse ») ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

On trouve parfois en langue anglaise plus ou moins récemment des noms ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outrage%20%2A_NOUN%2Coutrage%20industry&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Coutrage%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boutrage%20humanity_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20decency_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20nature_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20truth_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20reason_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20probability_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20society_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20propriety_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20economy_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutrage%20industry%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Coutrage%20*_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boutrage%20humanity_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20decency_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20nature_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20*_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20truth_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20reason_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20probability_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20society_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20propriety_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boutrage%20economy_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutrage%20industry%3B%2Cc0) ; contexte : [1](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2014/01/angry-politics-americans-addicted-101735/), [2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254321803_From_Incivility_to_Outrage_Political_Discourse_in_Blogs_Talk_Radio_and_Cable_News)) composés avec le nom [*outrage*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/outrage/599504) tels *outrage porn/discourse/media/politics/journalism* et signifiant généralement du contenu « created not in order to generate sympathy, but rather to cause anger or outrage among its consumers » ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outrage_porn)) [...conçu afin de susciter la colère ou... de l'auditoire.].

Comment *outrage* [nom] dans le sens expliqué est-il traduit/transposé (avec *discours* etc.) ; est-ce avec un nom, un adjectif, un participe employé adjectivement ou autremenent ?

Comment: Outrancier ? ⁙⁙⁙

Comment: @jlliagre « Outrancier » porte à mon à mon avis une valeur négative  (dans l’excès) que n'a pas [*outrage*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outrage) qui connote avant tout l'expression de la colère (laquelle peut être positive et justifiée).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À mon avis c'est le terme **indignation** qui s'impose en français. Même si on peut trouver quelques exemples d'emploi  qui datent d'avant la parution du livre de [Stéphane Hessel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A9phane_Hessel) :  [*Indignez-vous !*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indignez-vous_!) (traduit en anglais par [*Time for Outrage!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_for_Outrage!)), j'associe le terme (et l'attitude qui va avec) à Stéphane Hessel.

Quelques exemples francophones :

> Les vives réactions entendues relèvent du journalisme d’indignation. ([Le Temps](https://www.letemps.ch/suisse/conseil-etats-entaille-liberte-presse), 16/06/21)

> Ce réflexe proprement puritain illustre l’actuelle substitution d’un journalisme d’investigation par un journalisme d’indignation...) [La revue nouvelle](https://www.revuenouvelle.be/Le-panoptique-participatif-ou-la-transparence), 12/12/2011)

> ... tous les champions du journalisme d'indignation aurait fait chauffer la toile et les associations de pleureuses subventionnées par nos institutions nationales... (Courrier des lecteurs d'un [hebdomadaire francophone](https://www.lepoint.fr/politique/tapie-une-possible-affaire-de-corruption-selon-eva-joly-11-05-2011-1329314_20.php), 11/02/2011)

> L’exaspération morale devant l’histoire conduit Gary vers des formes particulières de récit qui lui permettent de développer son discours d’indignation. ([Article universitaire français](https://www.fabula.org/colloques/document1321.php), 10/2010)

> Cet épisode témoigne parfaitement du danger d’abandonner aux élites le discours d’indignation... (un [media d'opinion](https://lvsl.fr/crise-sanitaire-pour-un-nouvel-imaginaire-politique-commun/) français, 23/03/2020)

> « ...co-auteur d'un livre sur ce qu'on appelle les médias d'indignation (outrage media)... » ([traduction de l'anglais](http://www.slate.fr/story/92237/hate-reading) sur slate.fr, 09/2014)

> Politique d’indignation et politique de justice ([article universitaire](https://www.cairn.info/revue-etudes-2009-1-page-9.htm) français, 2009)